# jQuery localtime, getting a non-supported date/time string error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-localtime/wiki/Usage

My elements are rendered on the page with JS so I apply the plugin to the element as follows:

```
    var format = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm a";
    var localise = function () {
        jQuery(this).text(jQuery.localtime.toLocalTime(jQuery(this).text(), format));
    };
    jQuery(".localtime").each(localise);
```

Problem is this results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: 01/06/12 14:43 PM is not a supported date/time string
jquery.localtime-0.5.js:183
```

The text being passed to the plugin looks like this "2012-06-01T21:43:15Z" any ideas? Am I calling the plugin incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: var date = jQuery(this).text(); console.log(date);jQuery(this).text(jQuery.localtime.toLocalTime(date, format));  Could you paste what is in the console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xJxxR/ It works, it means that the problem is the content of your div...

Comment: Strange, it does work in the jsfiddle which make me think the error is due to the implementation above, perhaps something with the lopping?

Comment: What the message explicitly say is that you have passed 01/06/12 14:43. The reason could be that you execute it twice...

Comment: yep that's the issue, it keeps reapplying

Comment: Maybe post the rest of the js, if you can't resolve it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the localtime plugin automatically applies the formatting on the page load; so the formatting is applied when the page loads, and again using the code you supply above.

Either prevent the plugin from applying the style by default:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$.localtime.setFormat({});</script>
```

Or remove your code that attempts to re-apply it a second time.